# CharIndex exact match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a parameter being passed into a usp that is a varchar(max). This parameters is something like the following:

```
'1,20,3,40,0'
'1,5,30,0,5,9'
'0,50,40,8,9'
'1,10,2,3,4'
```

I need to figure out if the parameter has a value of just 0 in it anywhere. I was going to use:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('0',@DispIDs) > 0 
     THEN convert(bit,1) 
     ELSE convert(bit,0) 
END
```

But this still returns a true on values like 40, 30, etc. I only want to mark it as true if the param contains the 0. So the last example would return false, the others would return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for it surrounded with commas, and wrap the initial string with commas to match (to cover `0` at the ends of the string):

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',0,',',' + @DispIDs + ',') > 0 THEN convert(bit,1) ELSE convert(bit,0) END
```